# On the initial conditions for bacterial population growth

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology

I want to prepare an example of a differential equation for bacetrial growth.

We have   $\frac{dy}{dt}=ry(t)$

Multiplying by dt and moving y(t) over to the other side we get $\frac{1}{y(t)}dy=rdt$, integrating both sides, we get
$y(t)=ce^{rt}$. If we say that the bacterial population at time zero is y(0)=10.000 CFU, and at time 1, y(1)=200.000, then we have the system

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}
f10000=ce^{r0}\\
200000=ce^{r}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

We get from the first equation $c=10000$. We plug it into the second, and get that $r=ln20$.

We now have the growth equation:

$y(t)=10000e^{ln20t}$

and by Moos suggestion:

$y(t)=10000t^{20}$

Would this be correct, in its simplicity?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, added your form.

Comment: @Moo, are you aware of any peer reviewed article that uses this formula for bacteria growth? I looked, but can't find it. For instance, for $lactobacillus$. Thanks

Comment: Thanks Moo. I looked on a general search for bacteria, and found this, which lists this equation as equation (1). https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6598210/